# How to make a clickable notification firebase with angular

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification

I want to make the notification redirect to designated URL by clicking it. By the way, I'd try  *self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event)* before but still no luck

This is the example of foreground notification [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4YPP.png)

Below is my messaging.service.ts:

```
   constructor(
    private angularFireDB: AngularFireDatabase,
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging,
    private swPush: SwPush, 
  ) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    );
  }

  private compInstance = new Subject<any>();
  comp$ = this.compInstance.asObservable();

  updateToken(userId, token) {
    // we can change this function to request our backend service
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      () => {
        const data = {};
        data[userId] = token
        this.angularFireDB.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
      })
  }

  requestPermission(userId) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        //console.log("Your token firebase is: " +token);
        if (localStorage.getItem("FirebaseToken") === null) { 
          localStorage.setItem("FirebaseToken", token); 
        }                                                   
        this.updateToken(userId, token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
        this.compInstance.next(); 
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      })
  }
}
```